# Dynamic Query / escapeSingleQuotes And "no viable alternative at character '\'"

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql

Read all the articles, tried most everything but cannot find a solution other than faith that users will not enter malicious data but:

I am trying to create a user entered query filter but when I use `string.escapeSingleQuotes()` as suggested it all breaks with:

> no viable alternative at character '\'

Yet if I use the debug of the constructed query, put it in execute anon and wrap it in ' then the query works....

So how then do I take a user entered where clause and append it to an dynamic query string and perform the query safely.

Reproducible example

**Class**

```
public with sharing class Example_Controller {


    public string whereClause {get;set;}
    public string results {get;set;}

    public void doQuery(){
        results = null;

        String tmp = whereClause == null ? 'Where Id != null' : (' Where ' + string.escapeSingleQuotes(whereClause));
        integer d;

        try{
            d = database.countQuery('Select Count() From Contact ' + tmp);
            results = 'Found ' + d + 'Contact(s)';
        }catch(Exception e){
            results = e.getMessage();
        }
    }

}
```

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page id="Example_Page" controller="Example_Controller">

    <apex:form id="tmp">
        <apex:inputText value="{!whereClause}"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!doQuery}" value="Click Me"/>
        <apex:outPutPanel layout="block" rendered="{!!isBlank(results)}">
            {!results}
        </apex:outPutPanel>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Using the user input:

> Name Like 'Liz%'

I get the following on the screen[image]

Now, if I remove the `string.escapSingleQuotes()` it works fine but it is vulnerable:

```
String tmp = whereClause == null ? 'Where Id != null' : (' Where ' + whereClause); //string.escapeSingleQuotes(whereClause));
```

[image]

How do I construct the dynamic query string to safely perform this count query as well as regular SOQL queries......

The **GOAL** here is so an advance user can type in a query where clause that could be anything (validated prior to execution) so that a specific query can be filtered according to their needs. It needs to be generic and simple....

**Initial Result**

based on comments below I contracted this hacked together quickly test and it seems to work....Any comments on making it better?

```
public static String parseWhereClause(String whereClause){
    if(whereClause == null) return '';


    String[] tmp = whereClause.replace('\\','').split('\'');

    String result = tmp[0];
    if(tmp.size() > 1){
        for(integer x=1;x<tmp.size();x++) {
            result += '\'' + string.escapeSingleQuotes(tmp[x]) + '\'';

            if(tmp.size() > x+1){
                x++;
                result += tmp[x];

            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

The above at least throws an error when trying to use an injection query string:

```
%' or Performance_rating__c<2 or name like '%
```

And work fine for both

```
Name Like 'Liz%'
Name Like \'Liz%\'
```

Although like sfdcfox says allowing the string to be typed in essentially is in itself an SOQL injection. But in this case I expect the user to specify the records returned and the class respects sharing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Allowing total control of the where clause is, by definition, an injection vulnerability. It is for this reason that most forms expect users to enter either just a value, where the fields are in control of the developer, or provide a dropdown of fields they select from. Either way, if you're allowing the user to just put whatever they want for the WHERE clause, they can just type in something like `IsDeleted = FALSE` and get all the records in the database (assuming, of course, they don't hit governor limits first). The String.escapeSingleQuotes function is designed to escape just a value, not an entire field-operator-value tuple.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation on why it does not work like I am using it. So basically since both answers say it cannot be done I am going to have to go with a "Select field, operator, enter criteria" type model where they will have to build it out.....Sucks

Comment: @Eric Unless you're willing to write a full SOQL validator, or perhaps some sort of simplistic formula language evaluator, I'm afraid that's your answer. It's not impossible, but it *is* very hard to do correctly.

Comment: Can you look at my hacked together solution in my question? it works with both `'` and `\'` characters in the string....Curious if you can see any major flaws / improvements without putting in much effort.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior. If you look at the output query string, you'll see:

```
SELECT count() FROM Contact WHERE Name LIKE \'Liz %\'
```

Of course you cannot run this query. I'm not sure how much you need to worry about injection vulnerability for a count query, but if you absolutely must prevent injection in this case, you likely have to specify field, operator, and value all separately.

Comment: Yea, that was what I found in the part about copying the output and wrapping it in `'` working fine

Comment: Count query was easiest but will be doing SOQL as well. No idea what fields I would even need. The desired result is the advanced user can type in the Where clause and be able to use it. I really need to have a way to do that and be OK on the security gods side

Comment: Same comment as I made to sfdcfox. Thank you gentlemen

Comment: @Eric Your updated solution isn't going to work that well, especially if you have any escaped backslashes. I think you *must* use regular expressions. I spent some time on it, but they are going to be pretty complex if you want to validate an entire `WHERE` clause, especially factoring in `AND`/`OR` logic.

Comment: thanks Adrian. Looks like I need to change my expectations around this